# load reports In function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have read through the many questions associated with the error message:

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In f  unction `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
without finding the answer to this question.

I have:

```
Program InvertMultiply

implicit none
integer (kind=4),parameter :: nx=3
integer (kind=4) :: ipiv(nx)
integer (kind=4) :: info,i,j
real (kind=8) :: A(nx,nx), B(nx,nx), C(nx,nx), work(nx)
real (kind=8) :: alpha,beta

external DGEMM
external DGETRF
external DGETRI

A=reshape((/1,-1,-1,0,1,0,0,0,1/),(/3,3/));
B=A                           ! copy of A
call DGETRF(nx, nx, B, nx, ipiv, info)
call DGETRI(nx, B, nx, ipiv, work, nx, info)
alpha=1
beta=0
CALL DGEMM('N','N',nx,nx,nx,alpha,A,nx,B,nx,beta,C,nx)
print *,'A*Ainv'
do i=1,nx
  write(*,fmt="(6(1x,f4.1))")C(i,:)
end do
! should be diagonal
End Program InvertMultiply
```

which serves to make sure LAPACK routines are available.
I can compile and link with:

```
gfortran  InvertMultiply.f90 -llapack -lblas
```

`a.out` is produced and gives the correct answer

However if I break the compile link into 2 steps

```
gfortran -c InvertMultiply.f90

gfortran  -o InvertMultiply.o -llapack -lblas
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In     function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-o` specifies the output name, and not the objects... So `-o InvertMultiply.o` specifies the output to be `InvertMultiply.o`. Only the libraries remain, and they contain no `main`.

Please additionally specify an output file (or leave out the `-o` completely in which case the executable will most probably be `a.out`):

```
gfortran -c InvertMultiply.f90
gfortran -o InvertMultiply InvertMultiply.o -llapack -lblas
```

Comment: I happened to come here after getting an issue compiling a module so if anyone has that issue then make sure to use `-c` when compiling modules (maybe it's common knowledge, I am new to FORTRAN though so I am sure I'll have the error again at some point and see my own comment).